# Python IOError: Errno 13 Permission denied

Tags: python, recursion, ioerror

Ok, I'm totally baffled.  I've been working on this all night and I can't get it to work.  I have premission to look into the file, all I want to do is read the darn thing.  Every time I try I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    scan('test', rules, 0)
  File "C:\Python32\PythonStuff\csc242hw7\csc242hw7.py", line 45, in scan
    files = open(n, 'r')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test\\test'
```

Here is my code.  It's unfinished but I feel I should at least be getting correct values for the sections I am testing.  Basically I want to look into a folder, and if there is a file scan it looking for whatever I set my `signatures` to.  If there are folders I will or will not scan them depending on the `depth` specified.  If there is a `depth < 0` then it will return.  If `depth == 0` then it will just scan the elements in the first folder.  If `depth > 0` it will scan folders up until the specified depth.  None of that matters thought, because for whatever reason I don't have permission to read the file.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

```
def scan(pathname, signatures, depth):
'''Recusively scans all the files contained in the folder pathname up
until the specificed depth'''
    # Reconstruct this!
    if depth < 0:
        return
    elif depth == 0:
        for item in os.listdir(pathname):
            n = os.path.join(pathname, item)
            try:
                # List a directory on n
                scan(n, signatures, depth)
            except:
                # Do what you should for a file
                files = open(n, 'r')
                text = file.read()
                for virus in signatures:
                    if text.find(signatures[virus]) > 0:
                        print('{}, found virus {}'.format(n, virus))
                files.close()
```

Just a quick edit:

This code below does something very similar, but I can't control the depth.  It however, works fine.

```
def oldscan(pathname, signatures):
    '''recursively scans all files contained, directly or
       indirectly, in the folder pathname'''
    for item in os.listdir(pathname):
        n = os.path.join(pathname, item)
        try:
            oldscan(n, signatures)
        except:
            f = open(n, 'r')
            s = f.read()
            for virus in signatures:
                if s.find(signatures[virus]) > 0:
                    print('{}, found virus {}'.format(n,virus))
            f.close()
```

Comment: What exactly are the permissions on the file? Are you running the Python program with the same username as the one you used to try opening the file?

Comment: just execute `ls -l` and put output here

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I am the sole user of my computer, and as such, have Admin capabilities.  I'm confused because I do have code that does something similar that works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I venture to guess that `test\test` is a directory, and some exception occurred. You catch the exception blindly and try to open the directory as a file. That gives Errno 13 on Windows.

Use `os.path.isdir` to distinguish between files and directories, instead of the try...except.

```
    for item in os.listdir(pathname):
        n = os.path.join(pathname, item)
        if os.path.isdir(n):
            # List a directory on n
            scan(n, signatures, depth)
        else:
            # Do what you should for a file
```

Comment: 'test' is the name of the folder that is in the same folder as my .py file with the above code I'm trying to execute.

Comment: @DanielLoveJr In any case I suggest to get rid of the try/except; it probably hides the original error.

Comment: So then I would check if uh... os.path.isdir(n) == True?  And if it's true then that's one of the folders?  If it's false then it's a file and I read it?

Comment: Well I can get it to work for 0, but now no matter what depth I give it, I just get the same results as if depth == 0

Comment: @DanielLoveJr Your function actually does nothing if `depth > 0`. Your `if` statement does not have such branch. But this is unrelated to the IOError which is the topic of the question.