# Error 13 Permission Denied Python

Tags: python, compiler-errors, python-2.4

I am trying to write a code to compare directories (sub directories and files within), then copy the contents of the other directory (files only including files in the sub-directories) to the other directory. I imported everything then I have this:

```
dst = "C:/somefolder" 
path = "C:/otherplace"
compare = filecmp.dircmp(path,dst)
ans = compare.right_only 
for fil in ans:
  if len(ans)>0:
    shutil.copy2(dst,path)
```

i have tried other routes using os.listdir but i always seem to end up at the error

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

this written in python 24

I am running my code using cygwin but i am a windows user

Comment: You don't have the right to write in that location. To verify, go to that path and try making a new folder. Can you make one?

Comment: i can make new folder and i am admin

Comment: If you are on a windows machine, try running your script as a administrator. `run as administrator`

Comment: I don't how to do that.

Comment: right click the cmd.exe and hit "Run as administrator"

Comment: i did that and i am still getting the same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python IOError: Errno 13 Permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246114/python-ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied)