# IOError [Errno 13] when using numpy.loadtext?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that polls a folder for new files, then loads them using numpy.loadtext when it shows up. The function is called from a while loop that runs for 30 seconds. The function works properly most of the time, but for some files, seemingly at random, I get the error IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'myfilename1.txt'. Here is the content of my function:

```
before = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(mydir)])
while 1:
    after = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(mydir)])
    added = [f for f in after if f not in before]

    # New File
    if added:
        raw = numpy.loadtxt(mydir + added[0])

        return raw
```

Any idea on why this is happening? It properly polls and reads most text files that are incoming, but sometimes spits the error and I can't find a systematic reason why.

UPDATE:

Has something to do with using the full path with loadtxt. When I change the working directory to the directory where the files are, I no longer get the permissions error.

Comment: this doesn't sound like a `numpy` issue; it sounds like a permissions issue.  does your user account have permission to access these particular files?

Comment: Fairly sure it's not a permissions issue since it doesn't affect all incoming files. Going to try the suggested answer and see if that helps.

Comment: Has something to do with using the full path with loadtxt. When I change the working directory to the directory where the files are, I no longer get the permissions error.

Comment: again, this sounds like a permissions issue.  at the time of the call to `loadtxt`, there isn't permission to enter the directory -- but if you enter it beforehand, the problem is circumvented.  (certainly `loadtxt` in general has no problem working with full paths.)

Comment: I'm in windows and using an Admin account so that'd be odd. How can I go about checking this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the file as read only, may be a conflict if the file is accessed by another application (or is still currently being created).

```
# New File
if added:
    with open(mydir + added[0], 'r') as f:
        raw = numpy.loadtxt(f)
```

You could also try some form of IOError handling which waits a little while and then tries again

```
import time

before = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(mydir)])
added = False
while 1:

    # New File
    if added:
        try:
            raw = numpy.loadtxt(mydir + added[0])

            return raw
        except IOError: 
            time.sleep(5)
    else:
        after = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(mydir)])
        added = [f for f in after if f not in before]
```

Comment: Still doesn't work (constantly catches the exception, so it doesn't sound like an incomplete file issue). When I run the numpy.loadtxt from the command line it loads fine. Maybe a path problem?

Comment: Does the following link help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246114/python-ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied. May be because you try to open a folder as a file?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I attempted the following:

```
Y = np.loadtxt("C:/Users/erios/images_3_color_15k_labeled/", dtype='int')
```

I.e., I passed the folder where the text was located
INstead, the following command executed with no error:

```
Y = np.loadtxt("C:/Users/erios/images_3_color_15k_labeled/labels_for_locations.txt", dtype='int')
```

In sum, specify the full name of the text file, not just the folder.